# Stripe Payment Webhook

Tags: stripe-payments

In stripe invoice.payment_succeeded  events in webhooks response showing always Response 500.

My coding invoice_payment_succeeded event Below,

```
<?php 
 if (Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest) {

        try {
            /*
             * Initialize API
             */
            Stripe::setApiKey(Yii::app()->params['secret_key']);

            /*
             * Get and decode data
             */
            $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
            $event = json_decode($postdata);




            /*
             * Find the event in our database or save it if doesn't exist
             */



            /*
             * If the event hasn't been processed yet...
             */



                /*
                 * We don't manage all Stripe events but only relevant events
                 * 
                 */


                switch ($event->type) {

                                        /*
                     * When a payment success we get a invoice.payment_succeeded
                     */
                    case 'invoice.payment_succeeded':

                        Yii::log('', 'trace', 'stripe');
                        Yii::log('==================================', 'trace', 'stripe');
                        Yii::log('==== Event (' . $event->type . ') ====', 'trace', 'stripe');
                        Yii::log('==================================', 'trace', 'stripe');
                        $customer_id = $event->data->object->customer;                            
                        $customer = Stripe_Customer::retrieve($customer_id);                            
                        $invoice = Stripe_Invoice::retrieve($event->data->object->id);
                        $user = TblPackageUserplan::model()->findByAttributes(array('customer_id' => $customer_id));



                        /* Customer, invoice and user must exist */
                        if (!$customer || !$invoice || !$user) {
                            throw new Exception('No customer, invoice or user object retrieved');
                        }

                        $saved = false;

                        /* Begin db transaction, we will commit/rollback depending on possible exceptions */
                        $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
                        try {


                           Yii::log('Invoce period start: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $event->data->object->period_start), 'trace', 'stripe');
                            Yii::log('Invoce period end: ' . date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $event->data->object->period_end), 'trace', 'stripe');

                            /* Save transaction in database including post data 
                            if (!$this->saveTransaction($user, $event, $postdata)) {
                                throw new Exception('Transaction not saved', '400');
                            } else {
                                Yii::log('Payment transaction saved (not commited)', 'trace', 'stripe');
                            }*/

                            /* We updated local status here using lines. Now we use subscription's customer */
                            //$event->type sent by sathis to manage new plan upgrade
                            $this->manageSubscription($customer->subscriptions, $user, $event->type);

                            Yii::log('Commiting db transaction...', 'trace', 'stripe');
                            /* NO EXCEPTION, everything is ok. Let's commit */
                            $transaction->commit();
                            Yii::log('Done', 'trace', 'stripe');
                            /* This flag let us know if we have to send a email or not */
                            $saved = true;
                        } catch (Exception $e) {
                            Yii::log("Rolling back transaction", 'error', 'stripe');
                            Yii::log("Exception: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error', 'stripe');
                            /* Something went wrong, log the error, rollback and continue */
                            $transaction->rollback();
                        }
                        if ($saved) {
                            /* If everything ok, send an email */
                            Yii::log("Checking if user must receive email", 'error', 'stripe');

                                Yii::log("Sending", 'error', 'stripe');
                                if ($this->sendMailToUser($customer, $invoice)) {
                                    Yii::log("Mail (to user) sent", 'error', 'stripe');
                                } else {
                                    Yii::log("Mail (to user) not sent", 'error', 'stripe');
                                }

                                if ($this->sendMailToAdmin($user, $invoice)) {
                                    Yii::log("Mail (to admin) sent", 'error', 'stripe');
                                } else {
                                    Yii::log("Mail (to admin) not sent", 'error', 'stripe');
                                }

                        }
                }
        }

        catch (Exception $e) {
                            Yii::log("Rolling back transaction", 'error', 'stripe');
                            Yii::log("Exception: " . $e->getMessage(), 'error', 'stripe');
                            /* Something went wrong, log the error, rollback and continue */
                            $transaction->rollback();
                        }
 }


public function manageSubscription($subscription, $user , $event_type = '') {

$update  =   TblPackageUserplan::model()->updateByPk(62, array('create_date'=> '2015-08-08'));



 $period_end = $subscription->current_period_end;
 $period_start = $subscription->current_period_start;
 $plan = $subscription->plan->id;






    Yii::log('subscription is ' . $subscription->status, 'trace', 'stripe');
     if ($subscription->data[0]->status == 'active') {
    if (!$this->updateCompanyUserExpireDate($user, $period_end,$period_start)) {
                    throw new Exception('User not saved', '400');
                } else {
                    Yii::log('User data saved (not commited)', 'trace', 'stripe');
                }

    }           



 }
```

What's wrong in my code?Why i got response 500.I checked in Test Response once i changed that customer id and invoice id give static mean its working fine.How to take subscription details $customer->subscriptions or 
$customer->subscription? How to check invoice id and customer when current events?

Answer (score 0):

In your call to `manageSubscription()`:

```
$this->manageSubscription($customer->subscriptions, $user, $event->type);
```

you pass `$customer->subscriptions`. The [`subscriptions`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object-subscriptions) attribute is a *list* of [subscription objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object). But in the `manageSubscription()` method itself, you treat it as a single customer object.

If your customers will never have more than one subscription, it might be simple to change the call to:

```
$this->manageSubscription($customer->subscriptions[0], $user, $event->type);
```

Otherwise, you'll need to modify the method's body.

Inside the method, there's also this line:

```
if ($subscription->data[0]->status == 'active') {
```

If `$subscription` is a single subscription object, then the line should be:

```
if ($subscription->status == 'active') {
```

as subscription objects do not have a `data` attribute.

Comment: How to check  customer having multiple subscription or not?

Comment: `count($customer->subscriptions)` will return the number of elements in the `subscriptions` attribute, i.e. the number of subscriptions.

Comment: Why i cant update any data inside manageSubscription function in my database?plz refer my above coding